# How to properly do negative value cast to an unsigned type in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion, unsigned, misra

I want to store a register value and do the `bitwise NOT operator` like below

```
typedef union TEST_REG {
  uint32_t                         u32Register;
  uint8_t                          Byte[4];
  uint16_t                         hword[2];
} tst_reg;

#define TEST_REGISTER              ((volatile tst_reg*) 0x7023100CUL) // Register
```

Below is a sample code to store the value

```
#define CHECK_FLAG                  (0x00000004)
TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= (uint32_t)(~(CHECK_FLAG));
```

But when I perform the `TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= (uint32_t)(~(CHECK_FLAG));` code, `QAC` is throwing a warning like

```
Constant: Negative value cast to an unsigned type
```

I understood that if we do a `NOT (~) operator` the Hexa values will change to negative number.

So I would like to know how to properly do the negative value cast to an unsigned type ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want to handle single bits or bitmasks, you should use unsigned values from the beginning. Try `(0x04u)`

Comment: Unrelated to the question, it might be more intuitive to write the macro as `(*(volatile tst_reg*) 0x7023100CUL)` and then use the register as `TEST_REGISTER.u32Register`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast before using the `~` operator, or define CHECK_FLAG as a uint32 with a cast or by adding 'u' to the literal to specify it is an unsigned literal.

```c
~((uint32)CHECK_FLAG)
```

or

```c
#define CHECK_FLAG ((uint32)0x00000004)
#define CHECK_FLAG (0x00000004u)
```

See this page: [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1) for the different suffixes in C.

A literal without a suffix is always interpreted as an `int`. So let's take a look at what happens when you write:

`(uint32)(~(CHECK_FLAG))`

CHECK_FLAG, which is the literal `4` and therefore behaves as a signed int when inverting the bits, becomes a negative value as a result of the bit inversion.

`(uint32)(-5)`

Now you're casting a negative value to an unsigned type, which the compiler warns you about.

If you cast to uint32 to *before* you invert (or use an unsigned literal to begin with), then the inversion does not result in a negative value because the variable is already unsigned when you are inverting the bits, and unsigned values cannot become negative.

Comment: Aside: RE: "A literal without a suffix ...": C calls `0x00000004` an integer _constant_.  C defines 2 _literals_: _string literal_ and _compound literal_.  In C, `&` can be applied to a _literal_, but not to a _constant_.

Comment: “ before the `~` operator” is ambiguous. It could be earlier in the source code or earlier in expression evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

> But when I perform the `TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= (uint32)(~(CHECK_FLAG));` code, QAC is throwing a warning like
>
> ```
> Constant: Negative value cast to an unsigned type
> ```

In the first place, C has no objection to converting negative integer values to unsigned types.  The behavior is well-defined.  It is MISRA that objects.  In fact, MISRA fundamentally objects to applying the `~` to an expression of signed integer type, *and* it objects to converting a composite expression of signed integer type to a different "essential type category", such as unsigned integer.  I'm not sure exactly where QAC is coming from, but MISRA doesn't care whether the value of the expression being converted is actually negative.

The thing to do is to start with an unsigned integer in the first place.  You can do that by suffixing your constant with `u` or `U`: `0x00000004u`.  Alternatively, `stdint.h` contains macros for writing constants of explicit-width types, and by using the appropriate one of those, you can solve the signedness issue *and* avoid a cast:

```
#define CHECK_FLAG                  (UINT32_C(0x00000004))
TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= ~CHECK_FLAG;
```

Comment: `UINT32_C` is MISRA compliant (Amendment 3 rule 7.5). However it actually results in a type `uint_least32_t` and not `uint32_t` so these macros are unfortunate to use in systems with strict type requirements and MISRA C. There's a chance that `uin32_t` and `uint_least32_t` have different sizes and then this macro is dangerous, so I'd recommend to avoid it.

Comment: @Lundin, in an implementation that provides `uint32_t` at all, I don't see how `uint_least32_t` can be a different size.  The latter has to be at least 32 bits wide, and there must not be a smaller unsigned integer type with 32 bits or more.  The main use of `uint_least32_t` is where you don't want to assume that the implementation provides `uint32_t`, but the code in question is already making that assumption.

Comment: Hmm, I might have been wrong thinking `uint32_t` and `uint_least32_t` are treated as different types by the compiler, they actually aren't. `_Generic((x), uint32_t: /* ... */, typeof(UINT32_C(0)): /* ... */)` won't compile since it sees the same type twice. Just as if I had typed `unsigned int` there, come to think of it.

Answer (score 1):

> How to properly do negative value ...

With masking, best to use *unsigned* constants (there are no negative values then).  The `()` are not needed, but not harmful either.

Typically a *cast* indicates weak code.

```
// #define CHECK_FLAG                  (0x00000004)
#define CHECK_FLAG                  0x00000004U
// TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= (uint32)(~(CHECK_FLAG));
TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= ~CHECK_FLAG;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MISRA checker should already give a warning at `#define CHECK_FLAG  (0x00000004)`. This needs to have a `U`/`u` suffix to be MISRA compliant and that's the actual problem here.

Some other things of note:

- The parenthesis around an integer constant fills no purpose (but could be problematic in case of using this one together with other macros.)
- Adding a bunch of `0000....` in front of a hex number fills no purpose but to confuse the programmer. C is kind of broken/cheeky when it comes to hex integer constants. Assuming 32 bit system then `0x00000004` is of type `int`, `0x4` is of type `int`, but `0x80000000` is of type `unsigned int` and `0x100000000` is of type `long` or `long long`.

  Very easy to write subtle bugs because of this. As some RL anecdote I once took over a broken project for an 8-bitter with 16 bit `int` where they had made a habit of typing out zeroes just like this, fooling themselves thinking they were getting 32 bit numbers. While in fact the project actually contained a mix of 16 bit `int`, 16 bit `unsigned int` and 32 bit `long` and this was one of the main reasons why the entire program was broken.

Therefore the correct code should be:

```
#define CHECK_FLAG 0x4u
...
TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= ~CHECK_FLAG;
```

The parenthesis spam makes no difference for MISRA compliance in this case - it's just bloat so I removed it. The cast is no longer necessary either since all operands of the expression are unsigned, "essentially unsigned" as MISRA calls it, and then no casts are required.

Comment: Agree with the parenthesis issue - they are important if the macro is not a literal (to remove potential ambiguity on expansion), but in the case of literals, they are unnecessary

Comment: The `(uint32_t)` cast is probably redundant, too... `u32Register` is already `uint32_t` so the `&=` will be done in `uint32_t`, won't it?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah that's right, it's not needed since these are all "essentially unsigned". I'm having this knee-jerk reflex of always casting the result of ~ since I'm maintaining a lot of MISRA C:2004 code where the rules were slightly different :)

Comment: @Andrew (Although the type of `u32Register` is irrelevant for the `~` but I take it that was just a typo and you meant that `CHECK_FLAG` is already (likely) `uint32_t`. In theory it _could_ be `uint16_t` if it was a 16 bit system. And then we get in trouble with rule 10.6 if we don't cast.)

Comment: No... in that case, the cast is stil not required, as `TEST_REGISTER->u32Register &= ~CHECK_FLAG;` is equivalent to `TEST_REGISTER->u32Register = TEST_REGISTER->u32Register & ~CHECK_FLAG;`.  Thus `uint32_t = uint32_t & ( uint16_t promoted to uint32_t );`